# Problema al obtener el primer atributo del req.body en node.js ({ undefinednombre: 'jojo', color: 'rojo' })

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postman

Estoy iniciando en node, y al momento de querer capturar el primer atributo del body, este viene con el string undefined antecediendo el nombre de la clave `{ undefinednombre: 'Joe', color: 'rojo' }`, estoy usando el modulo queryString para parsear la data que recibo del body.

```
else if (req.method === "POST") {
            let data;
            req.on("data", (d) => (data += d));
            console.log(data)
            req.on("end", () => {
            let post = qs.parse(data);
            console.log(post);
            res.end("Elemento creado " + post.color);
        });`
```

Esta es la salida en consola de post:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con postman para hacer las peticiones http:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia `data += d` por `data = d`. No veo que tiene que hacer ese `+` ahí, si ni siquiera inicializas `data` a ningún valor, por tanto será undefined. Por otro lado, el código se pone a texto, no por imágenes.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez lo hice ahora (= en lugar de +=) la salida de la variable post es esta `[Object: null prototype] {}` pero gracias a la observación de la inicialización, inicialice `let data="";` y ahora si funciona pero con +=.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez. De hecho `data += d` es correcto porque los datos llegan en 'chunks' y hay que ir concatenandolos. Pero como dijiste el problema era que la variable no estaba inicializada